# Mediation analysis with two mediators in R

Tags: r

How can I perform a mediation analysis with two mediators?
I need two mediation models, one for the association between IV1 -> DV, mediated by M1 and M2 and another for the association between IV2 -> DV, mediated by M1 and M2.

```
id <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 4)
IV1 <- rep(c(2, 1), each = 2, times = 3)
IV2 <- rep(c(1, 2), times = 6)
DV <- c(4,3,2,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,5)
M1 <- c(1,1,1,3,3,5,3,4,3,4,2,4)
M2 <- c(3,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,4)
df2 <- data.frame(id, IV1, IV2, DV, M1, M2)
df2
> df2
# A tibble: 696 × 6
      ID IV1   IV2      DV    M1    M2
   <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2     1         4     1     3
 2     1 2     2         3     1     4
 3     1 1     1         2     1     4
 4     1 1     2         4     3     4
 5     2 2     1         4     3     4
 6     2 2     2         4     5     5
 7     2 1     1         5     3     4
 8     2 1     2         4     4     5
 9     3 2     1         4     3     4
10     3 2     2         4     4     4
# … with 686 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I tried with the mediation and lavaan packages but fail to get the results I need.

A summary(mediate(...)) table like this would be ideal. But how can I get two mediators into it?

```
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Nonparametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals with the Percentile Method

               Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME             -0.540       -0.646        -0.43  <2e-16 ***
ADE              -0.110       -0.219         0.00   0.052 .  
Total Effect     -0.649       -0.792        -0.52  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated    0.831        0.695         1.00  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Sample Size Used: 696
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered your other question about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603862/mediated-moderation-analysis-with-two-mediators-in-r).  I'm not sure what answers you're seeking that `lavaan` can't supply (especially if the mediators and outcome are continuous.  If what you want is the direct, indirect and total effects of `IV1` and `IV2` through both `M1` and `M2`, here is how you could do that in `lavaan`.  If this isn't what you want, you'll have to be a lot more specific about what results you want/need and what you did in `lavaan` to try to get them.

```r
library(lavaan)
library(dplyr)
id <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 4)
IV1 <- rep(c(2, 1), each = 2, times = 3)
IV2 <- rep(c(1, 2), times = 6)
DV <- c(4,3,2,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,5)
M1 <- c(1,1,1,3,3,5,3,4,3,4,2,4)
M2 <- c(3,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,4)
df2 <- data.frame(id, IV1, IV2, DV, M1, M2)

model <- "
  # Regression paths from IV to mediators
  M1 ~ a1*IV1 + a2*IV2 
  M2 ~ b1*IV1 + b2*IV2 
  
  # Regression paths from mediators to DV
  DV ~ c1*M1 + c2*M2 + c3*IV1 + c4*IV2
  
  # Indirect effects
  direct_IV1 := c3
  direct_IV2 := c4
  indirect_IV1 := a1*c1 + b1*c2
  indirect_IV2 := a2*c1 + b2*c2
  total_IV1 := a1*c1 + b1*c2 + c3
  total_IV2 := a2*c1 + b2*c2 + c4
"

fit <- cfa(model, data = df2)
parameterEstimates(fit) %>% filter(op == ":=")
#>            lhs op            rhs        label    est    se      z pvalue
#> 1   direct_IV1 :=             c3   direct_IV1 -0.209 0.261 -0.798  0.425
#> 2   direct_IV2 :=             c4   direct_IV2  0.001 0.337  0.004  0.997
#> 3 indirect_IV1 :=    a1*c1+b1*c2 indirect_IV1  0.209 0.547  0.382  0.703
#> 4 indirect_IV2 :=    a2*c1+b2*c2 indirect_IV2  0.332 0.587  0.566  0.572
#> 5    total_IV1 := a1*c1+b1*c2+c3    total_IV1  0.000 0.602  0.000  1.000
#> 6    total_IV2 := a2*c1+b2*c2+c4    total_IV2  0.333 0.602  0.554  0.580
#>   ci.lower ci.upper
#> 1   -0.721    0.304
#> 2   -0.660    0.663
#> 3   -0.863    1.280
#> 4   -0.818    1.482
#> 5   -1.179    1.179
#> 6   -0.846    1.513
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This code works, thanks! The other you sent before didn't work, so I tried simplifying by leaving out the moderation part. 
Do you happen to know how I can visualise these results in a mediation plot?

Comment: By the way, can I include a term for repeated measures? I've got a 2x2-within-factors design where each subject does 4 trials (therefore the ID specification).
The factors were significant in my anova for repeated measures but aren't in this model